# Guessing random number game error

Tags: java

Below Is My Code , I Cant figure out , how can i make the user to have only 4 tries then its say you lost , try again ? why cant this work ? i am doing something wrong in  the for loop ? or should i use another loop

```
public class JavaApplication11 {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     * @throws java.io.IOException
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        int random = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1);
        //  System.out.println("Random Number Is:"+random);
        double userinput = 0;
        BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Welcome To The Guessing Game!");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        System.out.println("Lets Start,Guess The Number:");
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
        userinput=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        for(int i=random;i<=4;i++)
        {
            if(userinput==random)
            {
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("You Won!");
                System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            }
            else {
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Wrong Guess,Try Again! Good Luck^_^");
                System.out.println("--------------------------------------------");
            }
            System.out.println("Created By XYZ!");

        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`for(int i=random;i<=4;i++)` looks suspect: there's no reason to initialise `i` to the random number picked by the computer.

I think you meant `for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)` instead.

Comment: your solution is just going to loop around 4 times printing the same message with no new input from the user.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put

```
 userinput=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
```

into your for loop if not successful.

```
else {
   userinput=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
   ....
}
```

also the foor loop should be

```
for(int i=0; i < 4; i++)
```

Answer (score 1):

There several mistakes in your program:
 1. You can not guarantee user inputs a legal number. So, U should judge if br.readLine() is a integer number. The code is:

`str =  br.readLine();
while(!str.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    System.out.println("Input Format Error!! Please Re. input:");
    str =  br.readLine();
}
userinput = Integer.parseInt(str);`
2. The for loop should be coded as below if you wanna tried only 4 times:
`for(i = 1 ; i <= 4 ; i++)`
3. In the for loop, you should have interface for Re. input when the answer is wrong.

`str =  br.readLine();
while(!str.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    System.out.println("Input Format Error!! Please Re. input:");
    str =  br.readLine();
}
userinput = Integer.parseInt(str);`
4. if you wanna loop this process for many times, you should put all codes in a `while(true){...}` loop.

Answer (score 0):

you have to look to "random" variable !! 
you initialised it like :          
   `int random = (int )(Math.random() * 10 + 1);`
sometimes it is >4 , that's the problem caused on the For iterator

Answer (score 0):

Here are my suggestion:
1.Read user input in each try.(BufferedReader with in the loop)
2.If user win break the loop. 
3.Loop should be run 4 times only,
`for (int i = 1; i <= 4; i++)`